# what should i do to solve this about android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

when i try to see my program in emulator i click on launch this avd in the emulator it shows this error "the emulator process for avd has terminated". when i try by click on "open android emulator:pixel.." in the top it shows this:

```
10:42 AM    Error Opening Emulator
                WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
                ERROR   | Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
                INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
                INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
                HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
                INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
                INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\NoteBook TANDIS\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_12724.ini
                glTexImage2D: got err :( 0x505 internal 0x1908 format 0x1908 type 0x1401
                ERROR   | Create color buffer failed.
                VCPU shutdown request
                VCPU shutdown request
                VCPU shutdown request
                INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.8.0 (build_id 8143646) (CL:N/A)
```

Comment: delete the emulator and recreate the emulator with resources

Comment: how can do it ? im beginner and know a little about android studio

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps first :

- Delete the emulator and create a new one again.
- Update the HAXM installer to the latest version
- Try running the emulator for lower APIs.

If this doesn't work, consider trying the following :

1. Go to **Tools -> SDK Manager**
   [SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ediwp.png)
2. In **SDK Manager** Go To **SDK Tools Tab** and unselect the **Android Emulator** and click on **Apply**. This uninstalls the Android Emulator.
   [SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUf8h.png)
3. After uninstallation completes: Again follow step 2 that is : **Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools** -> This time check the android emulator by clicking it.This step will install the Android Emulator again.
4. After installation is complete, Relaunch android studio and create new emulator device. Run it to see if the error still persists.

This worked for me